# Can anyone help me change this statement into a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I pretty much suck at subqueries and was wondering how to change this so it could be one. Output should be the same though.

```
SELECT COUNT(CUST_NO)
FROM CUSTOMERS
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS USING(CUST_NO)
WHERE ORDER_NO IS NULL;
```

Comment: why do you want that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NOT IN` operator:

```
SELECT COUNT(CUST_NO)
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE CUST_NO NOT IN (SELECT CUST_NO FROM ORDERS);
```

Or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(CUST_NO)
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS 
                  WHERE ORDERS.CUST_NO = CUSTOMERS.CUST_NO);
```

Comment: Note that the NOT IN result will be different than the original query's if the subquery returns a null value.

Comment: The NOT IN looks good to me. The way the OP wrote this query was a LEFT JOIN to ORDERS and a WHERE ORDER_NO IS NULL. Meaning there were no rows in the right table that joined to the left table. That's the same as a NOT IN. I give this an upvote.